# What is the correct version of tensorflow.compat.v1?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use tensorflow-gpu version.

When I try `import tensorflow.compat.v1`, it displays `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.compat'`

Environment:

```
protobuf                  3.19.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.6.13               h3758d61_0
tensorboard               1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-tensorboard    1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.10.0.2                 pypi_0    pypi
```

I found many ways, but there are still problems

Comment: Your tensorflow version is just waaaayyyyyy to old, there is also no need to use `compat.v1` if you are using 1.x anyway...

Comment: @xdurch0 What is the best version if I want to use ```compat.v1```?

Comment: @Itati, If we want to run `TF1.x` code in `TF2.x(i.e eager mode)` we generally use `tf.compat` module. It provide backwards and forwards compatibility across TensorFlow versions `1.x and 2.x`. Since here you are using `TF 1.5.1`, hence you don't required `compat` module. Thanks!